# Find maximum $2\sin 5x-3\cos x$.

Tags: trigonometry

Is it possible to find the maximum of $2\sin 5x-3\cos x $ without using calculus nor numerical methods?

I suspect there is a way to play around with trig identities until the expression is only in terms of either $\cos$ or $\sin$. I have done some trials but have only managed to make the expression messier.

Comment: I doubt this classifies as a simplification, but we can express everything in terms of $\tan\frac{x}{2}$. If you would like I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes. that's perfect.

Comment: Ok.. It's kinda messy so wait a few minutes please.

Comment: Might have made an error on that. I check it again.

Comment: Where did this question come from? It might help if you tell us the motivation for asking this question.

Comment: @Cataline From a trigonometry high school book probably - I found it in my notes. I think this $\sin 5x$ must have been supposed to be $\sin x$.

Answer (score 1):

what i have found is this expression
$$32\,\sin \left( x \right)  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{4}-
24\,\sin \left( x \right)  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}+
2\,\sin \left( x \right) -3\,\cos \left( x \right) 
$$
and the first derivative with respect to $x$ is given by
$$f'(x)=32\sin(x)\cos(x)^4-24\sin(x)\cos(x)^2+2\sin(x)-3\cos(x)$$

Comment: A big mess. Good. The answer to my question seems to be "no".

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$2\sin(5x)-3\cos(x)=\\2\sin(3x+2x)-3\cos(x)=\\2\sin(3x)\cos(2x)+2\cos(3x)\sin(2x)-3\cos(x)$$
We make use of the identities: $$\sin(3x)=3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x)\\ \cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$$
and $$\sin(2x)=2\cos(x)\sin(x)\\\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x)$$
Thus we obtain
$$2[(3\sin(x)-4\sin^3(x))(1-\sin^2(x))]+2[(4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x))2\sin(x)\cos(x)]-3\cos(x)=\\16\sin^5(x)-20\sin^3(x)+6\sin(x)+16\cos^4(x)\sin(x)-12\sin(x)\cos^2(x)-3\cos(x)$$
We can now make use of the rather obscure identities $$\sin(x)=\frac{2\tan(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}$$ and $$\cos(x)=\frac{1-\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}$$

to get an expression solely on terms of $u=\tan{\frac{x}{2}}$

Still,I am not sure if this will help though (in terms of not using calculus or numerical methods per request).

Comment: Just for fun, since your intent was of good will, this would take you to the following problem : what is the maximum of $$f(t)=\frac{3 t^{10}+20 t^9+9 t^8-240 t^7+6 t^6+504 t^5-6 t^4-240 t^3-9 t^2+20 t-3}{(1+t^2)^5}$$ I refuse to play with this monster.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Haha I was planning of calculating it a little later on, but kudos to you sir for doing this hard work and than you for posting it! If it looks menacing to you I will not dare go near it either.

Comment: As I said, the intent was good. But, back to serious, the plot this function is much less clear than the original one because the maximum is close to $x=\pi$ and the maximum will take place at $t=6.69357$. In this area, $f(t)$ is quite flat. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are allowed to plot the function for $0\leq x \leq 2\pi$. Doing it, you notice that the maximum is located close to $3$; let us say $\pi$.

So, use Taylor expansions around $x=\pi$ to get $$f(x)=2\sin (5x)-3\cos( x)=3-10 (x-\pi )-\frac{3}{2} (x-\pi )^2+\frac{125}{3} (x-\pi )^3+O\left((x-\pi
   )^4\right)$$ Ignoring all terms of degree higher than $3$, consider, as an approximation, that you need to find the maximum of $$g(x)=3-10 (x-\pi )-\frac{3}{2} (x-\pi )^2+\frac{125}{3} (x-\pi )^3$$ The derivative is $$g'(x)=125 (x-\pi )^2-3 (x-\pi )-10$$ which is just a quadratic. Solve it as usual and keep the root which is the closest to $\pi$; it will be $$x_*=\frac{1}{250} \left(3-\sqrt{5009}+250 \pi \right)\approx 2.8705$$ Now $$g(x_*)=\frac{539973+5009 \sqrt{5009}}{187500}\approx 4.7706$$

Using calculus (not simple), you would find that the maximum value of the function is $\approx 4.8613$ corresponding to $x\approx 2.8450$.

Comment: Isn't Taylor expansion contained in Calculus?

Comment: @choco_addicted. You are probably correct. May I confess that I do not know what are the boundaries of *calculus* ? At the time I took it, it was part of it but this was in France. It would very instructive for me if you tell what are, for you, the boundaries. I am serious asking this question. Thanks for answering. Cheers.

Comment: *Calculus 1*, written by Hong Jong Kim, deals with Taylor expansion in Chapter 3. [More info](http://www.yes24.com/24/goods/4283269?scode=029). Also *Calculus*, written by James Stewart, deals with it. [More info](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Calculus-International-Metric-James-Stewart/dp/0538498846/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1459687062&sr=1-1&keywords=calculus+james+stewart) I worry whether it is sufficient to answer you.